# Forcing the scroll bar to appear, without line break

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs in 1 row displayed as `inline-block`. When the container div, which contains those 3 divs, is minimized, I want a scroll bar to appear.
Unfortunately, in my case the 3 divs will be put into the next line, instead of displaying the scroll bar:

[image]

Only after all 3 divs were put to another line and there is no other possibility to minimize the container div, the scroll bar finally appears:

[image]

How can I always keep the 3 divs into 1 line and force the scroll bar to appear as soon as possible (when needed), without putting the divs into other lines?

```css
#container {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.myclass {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="div1" class="myclass">
    abc
  </div>
  <div id="div2" class="myclass">
    def
  </div>
  <div id="div3" class="myclass">
    ghi
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wea599a1/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this to the container so that the divs don't wrap.

```
#container {
   overflow-x: auto;
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wea599a1/2/

Answer (score 0):

Put a width on your container.

```
#container {
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 300px;
}
```

---

**All together now:**

```css
#container {
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 300px;
}

.myclass {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="div1" class="myclass">
    abc
  </div>
  <div id="div2" class="myclass">
    def
  </div>
  <div id="div3" class="myclass">
    ghi
  </div>
</div>
```